# error CS0664: Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float' for-non numerical text

Tags: c#

I am getting a 'error CS0664: Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'' for seemingly random lines of code. To elaborate, line 17 is getting the error. When I delete it, line 16 gets the error, them line 15 gets the error and so on.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace TutorialMod.Projectiles {
    public class SwordProjectile : ModProjectile {
        public override void SetDefaults() {
            projectile.width = 40;
            projectile.height = 1;
            projectile.friendly = true;
            projectile.melee = true;
            projectile.tileCollide = true;//15
            projectile.penetrate = 2;//16
            projectile.timeLeft = 100;//17
            projectile.light = 0.75;
            projectile.extraUpdates = 1;
            projectile.ignoreWater = true;
        }
        public override void AI() {
            projectile.rotation = (float)Math.Atan2((double)projectile.velocity.Y, (double)projectile.velocity.X) + 1.75f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was that the **entire** error message? I ask since https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5PkUp gives a different message which (importantly) tells you how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

`projectile.light = 0.75;`

to

`projectile.light = 0.75f;`.

This way you're telling compiler that it is a `float` value. Leaving it without a postfix character means it's a `double`, and that's when you get this error.

Comment: I don't know how i didn't see that. Thank you so much